# How to check if a string has any non ISO-8859-1 characters with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a string validator (or regex) for ISO-8859-1 characters in Javascript.

If a string has any non ISO-8859-1 character, then validator must return `false` otherwise `true`. E.g:

```
str = "abcÂÃ";
validator(str); // should return true;

str = "a 你 好";
validator(str); // should return false;

str ="你 好";
validator(str); // should return false;
```

I have tried to use the following regex but it's not working perfectly.

```
var regex = /^[\u0000-\u00ff]+/g;
var res = regex.test(value);
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you want to return false if **any** non-ISO-8859-1 character is present, you could use double-negate:

```js
var str = "abcÂÃ";
console.log(validator(str)); // should return true;

str = "a 你 好";
console.log(validator(str)); // should return false;

str = "你 好";
console.log(validator(str)); // should return false;

str = "abc";
console.log(validator(str)); // should return true;

str = "╗";
console.log(validator(str)); // should return false;

function validator(str) {
  return !/[^\u0000-\u00ff]/g.test(str);
}
```

It uses `!/[^\u0000-\u00ff]/g.test(str)`, since it checks if there is any non-character, and if it has not, it returns `true`, otherwise, it returns `false`.

Comment: is this the correct regex? I found `^[\x00-\x7F\xA0-\xFF]+$` at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s08.html. This regex reflects the removed chars you can find in the wiki article at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: @Icad That's because those regex are JavaScript, and the ones you found are not. There are a few variations between languages.

Comment: understand, but still ins't the specified range u0000-\u00ff wrong since there are non iso-8859-1 control characters included (U+0080 to U+009F)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to have an alternative way ...

> ISO-8859-1 - for the Unicode block also called "Latin 1"
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

So, let try use some native function, that uses latin1 only input...

> Base64, by design, expects binary data as its input. In terms of JavaScript strings, this means strings in which each character occupies only one byte. So if you pass a string into btoa() containing characters that occupy more than one byte, you will get an error, because this is not considered binary data
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa

```
const validator = (str) => {
  try {
    btoa(str)
    return true;
  } catch () {
    return false;
  }
}
```

btoa will throw following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
> at :1:1

See also: [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)